# When is a random number generated in a Keras Lambda layer?

Tags: tensorflow, lambda, keras

I would like to apply simple data augmentation (multiplication of the input vector by a random scalar) to a fully connected neural network implemented in Keras. Keras has nice functionality for image augmentation, but trying to use this seemed awkward and slow for my input (1-tensors), whose training data set fits in my computer's memory.

Instead, I imagined that I could achieve this using a Lambda layer, e.g. something like this:

```
x = Input(shape=(10,))
y = x
y = Lambda(lambda z: random.uniform(0.5,1.0)*z)(y)
y = Dense(units=5, activation='relu')(y)
y = Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(y)
model = Model(x, y)
```

My question concerns when this random number will be generated. Will this fix a single random number for:

- the entire training process?
- each batch?
- each training data point?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using this will create a constant that will not change at all, because `random.uniform` is not a keras function. You defined this operation in the graph as `constant * tensor` and the factor will be constant.

You need random functions "from keras" or "from tensorflow". For instance, you can take `K.random_uniform((1,), 0.5, 1.)`.

This will be changed per batch. You can test it by training this code for a lot of epochs and see the loss changing.

```py
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model
from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback

import numpy as np


ins = Input((1,))
outs = Lambda(lambda x: K.random_uniform((1,))*x)(ins)
model = Model(ins,outs)

print(model.predict(np.ones((1,1))))
print(model.predict(np.ones((1,1))))
print(model.predict(np.ones((1,1))))

model.compile('adam','mae')
model.fit(np.ones((100000,1)), np.ones((100000,1)))
```

If you want it to change for each training sample, then get a fixed batch size and generate a tensor with random numbers for each sample: `K.random_uniform((batch_size,), .5, 1.)`.

---

You should probably get better performance if you do it in your own generator and `model.fit_generator()`, though:

```py
class MyGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, inputs, outputs, batchSize, minRand, maxRand):
        self.inputs = inputs
        self.outputs = outputs
        self.batchSize = batchSize
        self.minRand = minRand
        self.maxRand = maxRand

    #if you want shuffling
    def on_epoch_end(self):
        indices = np.array(range(len(self.inputs)))
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
        self.inputs = self.inputs[indices]
        self.outputs = self.outputs[indices] 

    def __len__(self):
        leng,rem = divmod(len(self.inputs), self.batchSize)
        return (leng + (1 if rem > 0 else 0))

    def __getitem__(self,i):
        start = i*self.batchSize
        end = start + self.batchSize

        x = self.inputs[start:end] * random.uniform(self.minRand,self.maxRand)
        y = self.outputs[start:end]

        return x,y
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not yet allowed to upvote your answer, but I appreciate your helpful answer.