# how to do addition to hidden layers results?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Suppose we have a neural network like this

```
input = layers.Input(shape=(num_inputs,))
out = layers.Dense(1028, activation="relu")(input)
out = layers.Dense(512, activation="relu")(out)
out = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(out)
output = layers.Dense(4, activation="softmax")(out)
```

if I want to do addition to any hidden layers results with a random number how the code should change??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to any hidden layers results with a random number as follows. [Reference and more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53932284/9215780).

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K 

ins = Input((1,))

out = Dense(1028, activation="relu")(ins)
out = Lambda(lambda x: K.random_uniform((1,))*x)(out)

out = Dense(512, activation="relu")(out)
out = Lambda(lambda x: K.random_uniform((1,))*x)(out)

out = Dense(256, activation="relu")(out)
out = Lambda(lambda x: K.random_uniform((1,))*x)(out)

outs = Dense(256, activation="softmax")(out)
model = Model(ins, outs)
```